# How to make JQuery/JQueryUI compatible with React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-ui

I'm converting some HTML code into ReactJS and am having trouble with Jquery/JqueryUI.

I import both files with:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import * as jui from 'jquery-ui';
```

In my componentDidMount() I have

```
componentDidMount() {
    jQuery(function () { 
        jQuery("#palettes").accordion({
            activate: function (event, ui) {
                furniturePalette.requestUpdate();
                //  wallPartsPalette.requestUpdate();
            }
        });
        jQuery("#openDocument").draggable({ handle: "#openDocumentHandle", stack: ".draggable", containment: 'window', scroll: false });
        jQuery('#optionsWindow').draggable({ handle: "#optionsWindowHandle", stack: ".draggable", containment: 'window', scroll: false });
        jQuery("#removeDocument").draggable({ handle: "#removeDocumentHandle", stack: ".draggable", containment: 'window', scroll: false });
        jQuery("#myOverviewWindow").draggable({ handle: "#myOverviewWindowHandle", stack: ".draggable", containment: 'window', scroll: false });
        jQuery('#statisticsWindow').draggable({ handle: "#statisticsWindowHandle", stack: ".draggable", containment: 'window', scroll: false });
        jQuery("#selectionInfoWindow").draggable({ handle: "#selectionInfoWindowHandle", stack: ".draggable", containment: 'window', scroll: false });
        jQuery("#myPaletteWindow").draggable({ handle: "#myPaletteWindowHandle", stack: ".draggable", containment: 'window', scroll: false });
        jQuery("#myPaletteWindow").resize(function () {
            furniturePalette.requestUpdate();
            //wallPartsPalette.requestUpdate();
        });
    });
```

I use 'jQuery' instead of '$' since '$' is used with another library I'm using.

When I run this I get

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8_jquery__(...).accordion is not a function
```

If I replace 'jQuery' with 'jui' I get:

```
TypeError: name.split is not a function
```

(this error is in a jquery-ui subdirectory).

Does anyone have a solution?

## Solution

Just write:

```
import * as  jQuery from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle';
```

Comment: My guess is that importing them like that doesn't link them, i.e. jQueryUI's additional functions don't extend `$` as expected. Try using `jquery-ui-bundle` instead, which seems to work for people.

Comment: When I try this I get 'TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9_jquery_ui_bundle__ is not a function'

Comment: Did you try `import * as jui from 'jquery-ui-bundle';` ?

Comment: Yes, I installed it using 'npm install jquery-ui-bundle' and imported as so.

Comment: The error suggests you're trying to do `jui()` somewhere. I guess you need to stick to `jQuery()`.

Comment: I'm not calling jui anywhere else. Replacing with jQuery yields the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as  jQuery from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle';
```